# Appending a line with slashes to a file using sed - bash

Tags: bash, sed, slash

I want to insert text before the first line of a file. I want to use sed and command 
`sed -i '1s/^/line_to_be_added\n/' file.txt` works fine, but when I want to add directory path and use slashes in command I get an error `sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to`s'. My command `sed -i '1s//var/log/firstlogs/logs/first.json\n/' file.txt` How to escape slashes in this case?

Comment: `sed -i '1s/^/\/var\/log\/firstlogs\/logs\/first.json\n/' file.txt`

Comment: Thank You, works great!